# Is there a way to convert PowerPoint slides to images in flutter on Windows platform?

Tags: windows, flutter, dart

I'm working on an application, and I need to open a Microsoft PowerPoint file, convert its slides into images, and then display each one as a background.
Is there a way to do it now in flutter/dart?